# Use custom user name field for auth

Tags: laravel-9

I need to use a custom users table to authenticate with Laravel9.

The users table has a login_id field instead of "name" field and I would like to authenticate user with it.
In Laravel8, it was possible to change the field with adding below lines in LoginController.php.

```
public function username()
{
    return 'login_id';
}
```

However, I noticed that LoginController.php is missing in app\Http\Controllers\Auth folder! Is it normail in Laravel9? Which file should I change then?

By the way, I tried to add a "name" field to the table if it would work and it worked. So, auth is working ok.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. Hope this will help somebody:

Change name to login_id in the form (resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)

app/Http/Requests/Auth/LoginRequest.php

```
- 'email' => ['required', 'string'],
+ 'login_id' => ['required', 'string'],
```

```
- if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
+ if (! Auth::attempt($this->only('login_id', 'password'), $this->boolean('remember'))) {
```

If you want to use registration:

app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisteredUserController.php

```
- 'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
+ 'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:login_id'],
```